# how to update a github repo from a template using git api

Tags: python, github

On my project, I manage to create from the github api a repository using a github template. What will happen is that in the meantime I can upgrade my template project and therefore I would like to update it at the level of the private repositories that use it as a base.

I use this to line in python to create a repository from template.

```
import json
import requests

...

url='https://api.github.com/repos/{}/{}/generate'.format(owner, repo)
data = {
    'owner': 'owner...',
    'name': 'cp-app',
    'description': 'This is starter IDE kit for constraint programing.',
    'include_all_branches': False,
    'private': True
}
response=requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))

if response.status_code == 201:
     # ok
else:
    # error
```

I searched the github documentation but couldn't find it. Does anyone know of a way to update it?

Answer (score 1):

Using Github APIs, you can create repositories, change repository settings, do all operations that GitHub supports, but can't update repository content. Updating content is basically a **git operation**, not Github API operation.

To update contents of repositories (whether or not created using a Github template repo), you have to use **git client** itself.

If you want to update repositories using Python itself, then you can use libraries like [GitPython](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html) or run git cli commands via modules like *subprocess*. But this lead to unnecessary complexities in code, unwanted merge conflicts or code reverts.

So I would prefer manually updating all repositories manually using git client whenever a template repo gets updated.